# UDP sending but not receiving

Tags: c#, udp

I'm working on creating a UDP socket to send and receive data through the PC and a radio terminal device connected to the PC. I can successfully send the data that I want to send, but when it comes to receiving data sent from the radio device to the PC nothing happens the code just stops at the " Byte[] receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref ipep); " in the Receive function and nothing happens afterwords. The radio device has an IP address = 192.168.1.191 and Port number = 50000. I've also tried to receive through " Byte[] receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint); " but still nothing the code also stops at this point and nothing happens afterwords. Below is the complete code that I have. Any help would be very appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace UDP_Socket
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

    #region Importand Definitions
    public UdpClient udpClient; 
    public String IPaddress;
    public String PortNumber;
    public IPEndPoint ipep;
    #endregion

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Connect();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
       if (udpClient.Client.Connected == true)
       {
           udpClient.Client.Close();
           udpClient.Client.Dispose();
       }           
    }

    private void Add_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       RadioCheck();
       Receive();  
    }

    void RadioCheck()
    {
       byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("at");
       udpClient.Send(data , data .Length);
    }

    void Connect()
    {
        IPaddress = "192.168.1.191"; 
        PortNumber = "50000";

        //Uses a remote endpoint to establish a socket connection.
        udpClient = new UdpClient();
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(IPaddress);
        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Convert.ToInt32(PortNumber));
        ipep = ipEndPoint;
        try
        {
            udpClient.Connect(ipEndPoint);
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully connected to: " + ipep.ToString(), "Connection", MessageBoxButtons.OK);                
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show("Problem connecting to: " + ipep.ToString(), "Connection", MessageBoxButtons.OK);                
        }
    }

    void Receive()
    {
        //Creates a UdpClient for reading incoming data.
        UdpClient receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient(50000);

        //Creates an IPEndPoint to record the IP Address and port number of the sender.  
        // The IPEndPoint will allow you to read datagrams sent from any source.
        IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        try
        {
            Byte[] receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref ipep);//RemoteIpEndPoint);

            string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

            Console.WriteLine("This is the message you received " +
                                            returnData.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("This message was sent from " +
                                            ipep.Address.ToString() +
                                            " on their port number " +
                                            ipep.Port.ToString()); //RemoteIpEndPoint
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: My suggestion is to get a network sniffer such as Wireshark and see that the UDP packets are reaching your PC first, and then try to figure out what's wrong if they are.

Comment: Try using 127.0.0.1 and check whether you can receive them on the same PC.  Are you sure the destination has the address 192.168.1.191?  Do both the sender and receiver have the same subnet mask?